# C++ How to sum cards for a card game?

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

So, I'm creating a game very similar to blackjack but until 31 instead of 21. This code pretty much prints the deck and then shuffles it nothing else. How am I supposed to make the cards have an int value so I can add them? For example, I'll give the user 2 cards and then display the sum of those 2 cards and ask him if he wants one more card. If the user stops then it's the dealers' turn.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include<string>
#include<cstdlib>
#include "card.h"
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;

const int CARDS_PER_DECK = 52;

class deckOfCards {
public:
    deckOfCards();
    void shuffle();
    card dealCard();
    void printDeck() const;
private:
    card* deck;
    int currentCard;
};
//prints the deck
void deckOfCards::printDeck() const {
    cout << left;
    for (int i = 0; i < CARDS_PER_DECK; i++) {
        cout << setw(19) << deck[i].print();
        if ((i + 1) % 4 == 0)
            cout << endl;
    }
}
//the deck
deckOfCards::deckOfCards() {
    string faces[] = { "A","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","J","Q","K" };
    string suits[] = { "H","D","C","S" };
    deck = new card[CARDS_PER_DECK];
    currentCard = 0;
    for (int count = 0; count < CARDS_PER_DECK; count++) { //populate the deck in order
        deck[count] = card(faces[count % 13], suits[count / 13]);
    }
}
//shuffles the cards
void deckOfCards::shuffle() {
    currentCard = 0;
    for (int first = 0; first < CARDS_PER_DECK; first++) {
        int second = (rand() + time(0)) % CARDS_PER_DECK;
        card temp = deck[first];
        deck[first] = deck[second];
        deck[second] = temp;
    }
}

card deckOfCards::dealCard() {
    if (currentCard > CARDS_PER_DECK)
        shuffle();
    if (currentCard < CARDS_PER_DECK)
        return(deck[currentCard++]);
    return(deck[0]);
}


int main()
{
    deckOfCards deck;
    card currentCard;
    deck.printDeck();
    deck.shuffle();
    cout << endl << endl;
    deck.printDeck();
    deck.shuffle();
    cout << endl << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        int sum;
        currentCard = deck.dealCard();
        cout << currentCard.print() << endl;

    }




    return 0;
}
```

Card.h

```
#ifndef H_card
#define H_card
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class card {
public:
    card(string cardFace, string cardSuit);
    string print() const;
    card();
private:
    string face;
    string suit;
};

card::card()
{
}

card::card(string cardFace, string cardSuit) {
    face = cardFace;
    suit = cardSuit;
}

string card::print() const {
    return (face + " " + suit);
}
#endif
```

Comment: Can we see the definition of the `card` type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to approach this would probably be to store the value on the card itself -- but in Blackjack, the Ace can be either 1 or 11 depending on the value of the rest of the cards, so you need to be able to account for that as well.

So, on `card` you could add an `int value` which is 1 for Ace, 10 for the royalty, and face value for each other card.

```
int values[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10 };
```

(When creating the cards, you can also compute the value as `std::max(count + 1, 10)` instead of using an array.)

Now you need a way to score the cards in the current hand.  Here is a generic function that can work with any container of cards:

```
template <typename T>
int score_hand(T const & cards) {
  int score = 0;
  bool ace = false;

  for (card const & c : cards) {
    if (c.value == 1 && !ace) {
      ace = true;
      score += 11;
    } else {
      score += c.value;
    }
  }

  if (ace && score > 31) {
    score -= 10;
  }

  return score;
}
```

---

As a side note, the deck should not be declared as `card* deck;`. You are managing your own memory here, and your implementation violates the [rule of three/five](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)). Instead, use an `std::vector<card>` (as in `std::vector<card> deck;`).

You should almost never need to explicitly use `new` in C++. Use a container like `std::vector` for dynamic arrays. Use `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` where you need to heap-allocate objects.